# Ubuntu 14.04 won't boot alongside Mint 16

Tags: dual-boot, mint

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop 64-bit alongside a pre-installed Mint 16.
I let the installer re-partition my 160GB HDD evenly between the 2 OSes.
It never asked me about GRUB, boot loader, etc.
Now, it immediately boots into Mint. No GRUB menu or anything.
What have I done wrong?!
Please help.

Comment: Try with the solution mentioned on [this post](http://askubuntu.com/q/88384/62483)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Boot Repair documentation, this should get you straightened out.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

Mint is basically the same Ubuntu under-cover (16 Petra is tweaked 13.10 Saucy). So the solution would be the same as for Ubuntu.

1. Boot into Mint and edit `/etc/default/grub`:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/default/grub
   ```

   Change the line

   ```
   GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=N
   ```

   to

   ```
   GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
   ```

   and save (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>)
2. Update GRUB configuration:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
3. Reboot and see GRUB menu with Ubuntu option.

If you don't see GRUB menu during boot, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> when screen turns purple.